# Scala immutable container class extended with mixins

Tags: scala, immutability

I'd like a container class that I can extend with some number of traits to contain groups of default vals that can later be changed in an immutable way. The traits will hold certain simple pieces of data that go together so that creating the class with a couple of traits will create an object with several collections of default values.

Then I'd like to be able to modify any of the vals immutably by copying the object while changing one new value at a time.

The class might have something like the following:

```
class Defaults(val string: String = "string", val int: Int = "int")
```

Then other traits like this

```
trait MoreDefaults{
  val long: Long = 1l
}
```

Then I'd like to mix them when instantiated to build my the particular needed set of defaults

```
var d = new Defaults with MoreDefaults
```

and later to something like:

```
if (someFlag) d = d.copy( long = 1412341234l )
```

You can do something like this with a single case class but I run out of params at 22. But I'll have a bunch of groupings of defaults I'd like to mixin depending on the need, then allow changes to any of them (class defined or trait defined) in an immutable way.

I can stick a `copy` method in the `Defaults` class like this:

```
def copy(
    string: String = string,
    int: Int = int): Defaults = {
  new Defaults(string, int)
}
```

then do something like

```
var d = new Defaults
if (someFlag) d = d.copy(int = 234234)
```

**Question ====>** This works for values in the base class but I can't figure how to extend this to the mixin traits. Ideally the `d.copy` would work on all vals defined by all of the class + traits. Overloading is trouble too since the vals are mainly Strings but all of the val names will be unique in any mix of class and traits or it is an error.

Using only classes I can get some of this functionality by having a base Defaults class then extending it with another class that has it's own non-overloaded `copyMoreDefault` function. This is really ugly and I hope a Scala expert will see it and have a good laugh before setting me straight--it does work though.

```
class Defaults(
    val string: String = "one",
    val boolean: Boolean = true,
    val int: Int = 1,
    val double: Double = 1.0d,
    val long: Long = 1l) {

  def copy(
      string: String = string,
      boolean: Boolean = boolean,
      int: Int = int,
      double: Double = double,
      long: Long = long): Defaults = {
    new Defaults(string, boolean, int, double, long)
  }   
}

class MoreDefaults(
    string: String = "one",
    boolean: Boolean = true,
    int: Int = 1,
    double: Double = 1.0d,
    long: Long = 1l,
    val string2: String = "string2") extends Defaults (
        string,
        boolean,
        int,
        double,
        long) {

  def copyMoreDefaults(
      string: String = string,
      boolean: Boolean = boolean,
      int: Int = int,
      double: Double = double,
      long: Long = long,
      string2: String = string2): MoreDefaults = {

    new MoreDefaults(string, boolean, int, double, long, string2)
  }

}
```

Then the following works:

```
var d = new MoreDefualts
if (someFlag) d = d.copyMoreDefaults(string2 = "new string2")
```

This method will be a mess if Defaults get's changed parameters! All the derived classes will have to be updated--ugh. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'm strictly speaking answering your question, rather suggesting an alternative solution. So your having problems with large case classes, e.g.

```
case class Fred(a: Int = 1, b: Int = 2, ... too many params ... )
```

What I would do is organize the params into more case classes:

```
case class Bar(a: Int = 1, b: Int = 2)
case class Foo(c: Int = 99, d: Int = 200)
// etc
case class Fred(bar: Bar = Bar(), foo: Foo = Foo(), ... etc)
```

Then when you want to do a copy and change, say one of the values of `Foo` you do:

```
val myFred: Fred = Fred()
val fredCopy: Fred = myFred.copy(foo = myFred.foo.copy(d = 300))
```

and you need not even define the copy functions, you get them for free.

Comment: So you've combined them through inclusion rather than inheritance. That certainly looks better and won't require cascading changes. You are correct that once I divide the vals up there probably won't be a problem with the magic 22. BTW there is no problem with making myFred a var is there since the object it refers to is immutable, right? So you could write ```myFred = myFred.copy(foo = myFred.foo.copy(d = 300))```

Comment: You could, but thats not very FP

Comment: Also I was experimenting with having a case class that extends traits who contain the other default vals. Are the tacked on vals accessible using the case class's ```.copy```?  The trait vals do not seem to be supported by Default's copy even though they are accessed by the ```val a = Defaults().traitValName``` I guess because they are not named in a constructor. If this did work it would save the extra level of nested copy making the copy simpler to read.

Comment: As to reassigning the copy modified case class to the var, I'm keeping it in an instance var so the rest of the code will know where to find it. Not pure FP but at least immutable so lacking side effects, right?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that because when you call `copy` you will be copying everything and so essentially creating a completely new thing.  In which case you gain nothing from having it var.  I would only use vars in short local scope for imperative optimizations - i.e. where FP won't perform.

Comment: Because ```myFred = myFred = myFred.copy(foo = myFred.foo.copy(d = 300))``` is not the most readable thing. Actually I ended up just using an immutable HashMap[String, Any], the downside is that every time you read something you have to cast it. ```myFred = myFred + ("d" -> 300)``` then to read ```val v = myFred.get("d")asInstanceOf[Int]```. Another benefit is that you can just concatenate a bunch of defaults for a specific use ```val opts = GenDefaults ++ FileDefaults ++ SpecificOpts``` Where the various groups are constants. This seems the least verbose I can make it. Upvoted yours too.

Comment: Yes, using a Map is a nice idea. You shouldn't need to cast though - looks like your calling `.get` and therefore getting an `Option[Int]`.  What you should be doing is just `myMap("key")` and that will give you an `Int`.